# segmentation fault when assigning a string to stack.top()

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, postfix-notation, infix-notation, shunting-yard

I have been working on a basic calculator that can take in complicated mathematical expressions such as:(2-4)*7/(3/4) etc etc

I am using an implementation of the shunting yard algorithm...

I am on a linux OS. using the gdb debugger I have isolated a segmentation fault to one function.
using cout statements I have isolated it further to a single line..however I cannot fathom why this line is giving me a segfault..I will give more info on exactly where in just a moment, first here is some code..

```
bool infixToPostfix(const std::vector<std::string>& inputTokens, const int& size, std::vector<std::string>& strArray){
     std::cout << "1" << std::endl; 
     bool success = true;
     std::list<std::string> out;
     std::stack<std::string> st;

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    std::cout << "2\n";
    const std::string token = inputTokens[i];

    if(isOperator(token)){
        std::cout << "3\n"; 
        const std::string o1 = token;

        if(!st.empty()){
            std::cout << "4\n";
            std::string o2 = st.top();

            while(isOperator(o2) && ((isAssociative(o1, LEFT_ASSOC) && cmpPrecedence(o1, o2) == 0) || (cmpPrecedence(o1, o2) < 0))){
                std::cout << "5\n";
                st.pop();
                out.push_back(o2);

                if(!st.empty()){
                    std::cout << " 6\n";    
                    o2 = st.top();
                }
                else{
                    std::cout << "7\n";
                    break;
                }
            }    
        }
        std::cout << "8\n";
        st.push(o1);
    }
    else if(token == "("){
        std::cout << "9\n";
        st.push(token);
    }
    else if(token == ")"){
        std::cout << "10\n";
        std::string topToken = st.top();

        while(topToken != "("){
            std::cout << "11\n"; 
            out.push_back(topToken);
            st.pop();

            if(st.empty() ){
                std::cout<< "12\n";
                break;
            }
            std::cout << "13\n";
            topToken = st.top();
        }
        if(!st.empty()){
            std::cout << "14\n";
            st.pop();
        }
        if(topToken != "("){
            std::cout << "15\n";
            return false;   
        }
    }
    else{
        std:: cout << "16\n";
        out.push_back(token);
    }
}
while(!st.empty()){
    std:: cout << "17\n";
    const std::string stackToken = st.top();

    if(isParentheses(stackToken)){
        std::cout << "18\n";
        return false;
    }
    std::cout << "19\n";
    out.push_back(stackToken);
    st.pop();
}
std::cout << "20\n";
strArray.assign(out.begin(), out.end());
return success; 
}
```

the segfault is occurring at `std::cout << "10\n";` when calling `std::string topToken = st.top();`

I will give some input/outputs

intput: `(8*2)`
outputs: `1
         2
         9
         2
         3
         4
         8
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         8
         2
         10
         11
         13
         14
         2
         10 
         segfault (core dumped)`

input: `(4/4)`
output: `1
         2
         9
         2
         3
         4
         8
         2
         3
         4
         5
         6
         8
         2
         10
         11
         13
         14
         2
         10
         segfault (core dump)`

there are a few more tests I ran that I could easily post here but they become very redundant, honestly. If you guys want to see more you need just ask and I will gladly provide more. However I feel like these two should provide enough info...

I know where the segfault is occurring and I have a hunch as to why..so if anyone can confirm to me why exactly the fault is happening that'd be great, and any solutions to the problem would be much appreciated.

P.S: any typos in the code are typos! I copied the code by retyping it since I am coding on a linux OS but I own a pc. With that being said...the code compiles without errors, any misspelled terms are typos!!

thanks again

EDIT: after giving it a few days and coming back to this I ran a few more tests on the code. This time using equations without parentheses.

input:`3-9`
output:`1
        2

        3 
        8 
        2
        3
        4
        5
        7
        8
        17
        19
        20
        segfault (core dump)`

input:`6/8`
output:
       `1
       2
       3
       8
       2
       3
       4
       5
       7
       8
       17
       19
       20`

So I am also getting a segfault when calling `strArray.assign( out.begin(), out.end() );`

Comment: You seem to trust that `size` is correct. If I were you I'd check size in relation to the vectors you are accessing via [i]. My guess is you've run off the end of a vector.

Comment: Secondly, it is simple to compile with electric fence or run it under valgrind (if you have the packages installed, if not they are standard packages, use yum or whatever package tool is appropriate to install them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following after the line `const std::string token = inputTokens[i];`:

```
std::cout << "inputTokens[" << i << "]: " << token << std::endl;
```

I think you'll find that there's a problem with the `inputTokens` vector or possibly `size` isn't correct.

Out of curiosity - why do you pass in `size` as an argument instead of using `inputTokens.size()`?

Comment: thanks a lot. After doing a lot more testing I found the issue to be with my tokenizer. And I used it as an argument out of a suggestion from a friend of mine, I don't specifically remember the reason as I've been workin on this for a long time.